# Accessing methods of a wrapper component from a child in React

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

Say you've got a child component which renders text, like so:

#### Child

```
 export const RatingsGoneBetter = () => (
    <TestContainer>
      <section>
        <h1>What could&rsquo;ve gone better with {this.props.getName()}?</h1>
      </section>
    </TestContainer>
)
```

And a parent...

#### Parent

```
class TestContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
  }

    getName () {
      const { userId, chef, john } = this.props

      if (userId === 50) {
          return john.name
      } else if (userId === 1) {
          return chef.name
      }
  }

    render () {
      return (
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      )
  }
}
```

### Question

How can I call the getName method in the child to render the correct name?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add `props` to the `children` element, you can make use of `React.cloneElement` . Also you need to separate out children into a separate component so that you can access the props being passed to them using `cloneElement`

Related Snippet:

```
const RatingsGoneBetter = props => (
  <TestContainer userId={1} chef={{ name: "codesandbox" }}>
    <Sample />
  </TestContainer>
);

const Sample = props => {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>What could&rsquo;ve gone better with {props.getName()}?</h1>
    </section>
  );
};
```

and in TestContainer

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>{React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
                return React.cloneElement(child, {getName: this.getName()}, null);
          })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6q80z6z7r)**